# rails twitter gem for multiple users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-gem

using the twitter gem I want to get all the followers of the authenticated user. I only get the followers of the registered twitter id for the application though.

I have a twitter.rb in the initializers which uses the consumer key/secret of the registered app on twitter

```
Twitter.configure do |config|
    config.consumer_key = '****'
    config.consumer_secret = '****'
end
```

When you login you do so via Devise. Then in the user profile the user can authenticate with Twitter and at that point I store the token and secret.

```
def create
    auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    currentAuthentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth['provider'], auth['uid'])
    if currentAuthentication
        flash[:notice] = "Logged in successfully."
    else
        current_user.authentications.create(:provider => auth['provider'], :uid => auth['uid'], :token => auth['credentials']['token'], :secret => auth['credentials']['secret'])
        flash[:notice] = "Authentication successful."
    end

    redirect_to authentications_url
end
```

Then at a later stage I authenticate that user with the information I stored and want to get his followers.

```
  def getwords
    # authenticate at twitter
    authenticationDetails = current_user.authentications.first()
    wordClient = Twitter::Client.new(
        :oauth_token => authenticationDetails.token,
        :oauth_token_secret => authenticationDetails.secret
        )

    # get the users followers
    #wordClient.update("I'm tweeting using the Twitter Gem.")
    cursor = "-1"
    followerIds = []
    while cursor != 0 do
      followers = wordClient.follower_ids

      cursor = followers.next_cursor
      followerIds+= followers.ids
      sleep(2)
    end

    return followerIds
  end
```

When I do wordClient.update I sent a tweet out from the registered application, and I also get the followers of the registered application.

I was expecting to sent out a tweet and get the followers of the authenticated user? Where am I going wrong? All examples I've been able to find are on the bases of twittering with one single user.

Comment: The code above actually works fine. The issue I had is that I miss a unique constraint on the uid in the authentication table which caused two entries for the same person.